# interactivePopGestureRecognizer causes the UITabBarController disables interaction

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `UITabBarController` with three tab bar items. The tab bar items has view controllers of the type `UINavigationController`. Each navigation controller has `UIViewController` as the top view controller. Each view controller on the top of the navigation controller stack has its own flow. When the user swipes at the edge of the screen to trigger `interactivePopGestureRecognizer`, and upon the popping out the view controller from the stack, the tab bar items becomes not interact-able. Any idea, why is this happening?

I can only interact when I push another view on top of the existing view controller.

Comment: I have the same problem, but a UITableViewCell disables interaction.  Only when swiping very quickly with the interactive pop does this occur.  Popping normally or sliding slowly does not disable interaction?!