# Quickly swiping back using default interactivePopGestureRecognizer disables interaction of a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, interactivepopgesture, transition-coordinator

I have a table view with rows which when selected I push a view controller onto the navigation stack.

If I use the interactive pop gesture to go back ***slowly***, everything works as expected.

Only when **very quickly** swiping from the left edge does the following behavior occur:

Selection and or dragging starting from the cell that was originally selected is completely disabled

All other cells work fine and table scrolls starting from any other cell.  Pushing a view controller and popping back fixes the problem.

I believe there to be a navigation bug related to this in iOS 7...This is iOS 9 and the behavior is repeatable since interactive pop's origination in iOS7.  I've seen similar issues, but none of their solutions work for this particular case:

[interactivePopGestureRecognizer causes the UITabBarController disables interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31244404/interactivepopgesturerecognizer-causes-the-uitabbarcontroller-disables-interacti)

[iOS 7, corrupt UINavigationBar when swiping back fast using the default interactivePopGestureRecognizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24226392/ios-7-corrupt-uinavigationbar-when-swiping-back-fast-using-the-default-interact)

I don't want to disable the interaction entirely as in:
    self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = nil;
or 
    self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;

I've tried all obvious things like

```
  [tableView reloadData]
```

and

```
  [self.view layoutIfNeeded]
```

in view will appear

Would love some suggestions - thought about presenting/dismissing a dummy vc in the case that the coordinator is interactive, but that's kind of ridiculous.

Comment: Same problem. Have you found a solution?